# How can I include PHP file in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, php

PHP code for including my file doesn't work in my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_dialog() {
    var box_content = '<div id="box_content"><?php include 'includes/dialog_box.php';?><a href="javascript:close_dialog()">close</a></div>';
    document.getElementById('dynamic').innerHTML = box_content;
}

function close_dialog() {
    document.getElementById('dynamic').innerHTML = '';
}
</script>
```

please, help.

Comment: You can use `ajax` for that

Comment: @d'alar'cop `"<?php include 'includes/dialog_box.php';?>" - this doesn't mean anything to the browser...` The browser never gets to see that...

Comment: I explained a couple of standard problems in my answer, but you should tell what exactly happens in your case and maybe post contents of `dialog_box.php` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opposed what the two answers say, that *should* work fine if this all is happening inside a PHP file and your included PHP script outputs something that doesn't clash with the the structure of JS you have.

Think of quote issues:

if your script outputs, say: `<p class='hey'>Hey there</p>`, it might be a problem with JS since the end output would look like this:

```
var box_content = '<div id="box_content"><p class='hey'>Hey there</p><a href="javascript:close_dialog()">close</a></div>';
```

Note the clashing quotes. I know you probably don't do that, but I want to tell you to be **very** careful with that stuff, especially quotes and getting out of the JS variable context.

---

The bottom line: **Make sure your included script actually outputs the HTML you want**. Also make sure you have no line breaks in it, because this is invalid in JS:

```
var box_content = '<div id="box_content"><p class="hey">
                   One line
                   Another line
                   </p>...';
```

and should be either in a single line:

```
var box_content = '<div id="box_content"><p class="hey">One line Another line</p>...';
```

or concatted:

```
var box_content = '<div id="box_content"><p class="hey">' +
                   'One line' +
                   'Another line' +
                   '</p>...';
```

---

To make sure it's clear (since you didn't say what the include script should do and what's the error you're having), because this is PHP, don't think the contents will update every time you call that JS function - it won't! PHP will render its output once and that's it, it shuts down as soon as it sends the content to the browser. So if your include script is supposed to do some kind of dynamic stuff (say fetching a random text from the database), then you'd need to make an AJAX call to load the fresh content every time. But judging by common sense and the looks of your code, this is not what you seem to be doing, just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** **PHP** code should be in a **.php** file, it doesn't works in a **.js** file so write your function in your main page (if you haven't already done so)
To prevent errors you may load the content of "**includes/dialog_box.php**" in a variable and then replace all `'` with `\'` with a tiny regular expression so you can be sure that there are no quotes wich clashes with JS ones:

```
var content = "<?php include 'includes/dialog_box.php';?>";
content.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

and then put *`content`*'s value inside your *`box_content`* variable:

```
var box_content = '<div id="box_content">' + content + '<a href="javascript:close_dialog()">close</a></div>';
```